# Particular maximal solution of the inhomogeneous equation $y^{'} = |t|y + t$ on $\mathcal I = \mathbb R$.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

> Particular maximal solution of the inhomogeneous equation $y^{'} = |t|y + t$ on $\mathcal I = \mathbb R$.

I've already solved this system in the homogeneous case $b(t)=0$, where I've found the solution (maximal) to be $t \mapsto \eta e^{\int_{t_0}^t |s| ds}$.

However, not I'm looking for a particular maximal solution of the inhomogeneous equation.

Maple gave me the following output:

[image]

However, this is by no means useful ? There got to be a way of finding a "nice looking" and "easy to interpret" solution ?

Comment: Sorry, I did a typo. I've now corrected everything.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not wrong, the solution given by Maple is "nice and easy to interpret", it just defined by parts :

$\left\lbrace \begin{array} f(x) = e^{\frac{x^2}{2}}+Ce^{-\frac{x^2}{2}} & if &  x \leq 0 \\
f(x) = -e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}+Ce^{\frac{x^2}{2}} & if & x > 0 \end{array} \right.$

Comment: Thank you, but I did a typo. It is corrected.

Comment: Oh, right, didn't see the typo